# Aggregator Pattern , SOA ( SplitJoin OSB)

Tags: java, service, soa, design-patterns, osb

I have Oracle Service Bus exposing a service that aggregates the responses from 3 different backends.

The big problem is that OSB is behaving very badly with large payload in response.

If the response has like 20 MB the soap message and it needs to be aggregated and transformed with xquery, xpath (functions provided by OSB) in the memory in about 700MB !!!! (really!)

This means OOME soon cause if 2,3 users made the request in the same time , game over.

So are there some open source alternatives for implementing the Aggregator Pattern Service (aggregate soap response from multiple backends) ?

I can do this myself via a WS that calls 3 other WS (for the beginning sequentially ,then in parallel) but I want to be know first if there are already such things in java (like OSB's split join) so i will not have to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try tuning up the OSB towards large payloads?

Comment: Well is tuned enough i say, however i need to access content so it is not a through path only and information i need is not in the header. each manages server node has 2GB ...problems are with xmlbeans in memory.I did not coded the message flow so i can;t touch the logic too much...

Comment: I am thinking os doing it via java callout to an ejb

Comment: A 20mb response sounds strange, did you tried to work it out. Anyway, did you avoid using wildcards (// and *) on you xquery/xpath? Avoiding those with big payloads may make a difference

Comment: Strange cause in the memory becomes so huge ....not because we receive 20 MB payload i hope :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Oracle OSB is Mulesoft ESB.

[Mulesoft.Org](http://mulesoft.org)

[Mulesoft Foreach command](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/Foreach)

I am not affiliated with mule in any way.

Comment: Even if you are...there would not have been a problem if it works fine :) ..Knew about , i will take into consideration for the near future...i was thinking to a faster solution